# Magento 1.9.3 CE : Custom page layout for products from specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, products

I have a web shop with 4 different categories and I need all the products from 2 categories to be opened in custom page layout!

For example:

All the products from **category 1 and 2** to be opened with (**template/page/custom-view-one.phtml**).

And, all the products from **category 3 and 4** to be opened with (**template/page/custom-view-two.phtml**).